# How to pass ref by props in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, ref, react-props

This is my components logic:

```
component_1
     |
     '------component_2
```

I have an input in component_2, and I want to put .focus () on it, but the function that will do this is in component_1, how can I do it?
And I think it will do the ref, if I'm wrong please correct me.

Comment: I not remove!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since React 16.3, you can use [`React.createRef()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs) in `Component1` and pass it to the `input` via `Component2` using [ref forwarding](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html):

```js
const Component2 = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <input ref={ref} />
));

class Component1 extends React.Component { 
  ref = React.createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => this.ref.current.focus(), 1000);
  }
  render() {
    return <Component2 ref={this.ref} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Component1 />, 
  document.getElementById('demo')
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```